# Create Class Instance with Mock Services in Angular Testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-material, angular9

I am working in an Angular 9 project. I have created a class that is the dataSource of a Material Tree in another component. I have really only written tests for components, not classes. **I am having trouble making an instance of this class in a test file.** I have made mock services and added them to the testBed in the test file, like so:

```
class MockMyService {
  getData() {...}
}

describe("DynamicDataSource", () => {
  let dynamicDataSource: DynamicDataSource;
  let mockMyService: MockMyService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: MyService, useClass: MockMyService }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockMyService = TestBed.inject(MyService);
    dynamicDataSource = new DynamicDataSource(null, null);
  });

  it("should create", () => {
    expect(dynamicDataSource).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

In the above I've made an instance of the class with `dynamicDataSource = new DynamicDataSource(null, null);` However, to correctly test the functions in the class, I need to set the properties to the mock service instead of null.

I would think I need to do something like this: `dynamicDataSource = new DynamicDataSource(null, mockMyService);`
However, trying that gives me an error of `Argument of type 'MockMyService' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MyService'. Type 'MockMyService' is missing the following properties from type 'MyService': baseURL, http, logging`

I cannot set these properties in MockMyService because they are private properties.
I am able to mock services like this in component tests, so I'm confused why I have to have these properties in these mocks.

Is there a better way to be testing this class? How can I make an instance of it in the test with a mock service?

Any advice would be a great help.

Here is the class (btw):

```
export class DynamicDataSource implements DataSource<DynamicFlatNode>, OnDestroy {
 dataSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private _treeControl: FlatTreeControl<DynamicFlatNode>,
    private _database: MyService
  ) {}

  connect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): Observable<DynamicFlatNode[]> {...}

  disconnect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): void {}

 ...lots of functions and logic...

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.dataSubscription?.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: The accepted answer works, but I was also recommended to test the methods in the class through a component (I use this in a component, and I was able to make an instance of the class with the mock services). This isn't directly unit testing though. So you'll have to pick between using `as any` or testing through a component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is not just because properties are missing but because `class MockMyService`  is not `class MyService`.

I have had similar scenarios in the past.

I think there may be a few ways to achieve this but easiest I found, may just be to utilize the type-assertion with  `as any`.

```
dynamicDataSource = new DynamicDataSource(null, mockMyService as any)
```

You may still get run-time errors if you do not stub/mock properties of `MyService` that the class `DynamicDataSource` would call/use.
But by mocking this would give you the ability to createSpies to achieve what I think your trying to test

```
class MockMyService {
 getData = jasmine.createSpy('getData'),
 logging = jasmine.createSpy('logging')
 ....
```

}

Note: Been on projects in past were this was viewed as kinda hacky because in a way overriding the TS, but also some where the test coverage was more important.